# Are there any SOT-23 BJT's with swapped Base and Emitter pins?

Tags: bjt, surface-mount, packages

The standard NPN BJT in SOT-23 package has the following arrangement of pins:

[image]

Do you know of any transistor that has pins 1 and 2 reversed? So that 2 is the **base** while 1 is the **emitter** (Doesn't matter if NPN or PNP, i.e. Emitter or Collector). I truly can't seem to find such a device.

Comment: Why do you need such a package?

Comment: If you are doing manual soldering for a one-off, you could solder it on upside down.

Comment: Because I failed at routing and the PCB is already on its way. Also it would look cleaner than soldering upside-down. Just a nitpick.

Comment: Upside down with bent over pins is hardly distinguishable. Just ask any of my customers that I gave any of my early prototypes from the period 1996 to 2003. (Libraries and being paid well for the time started making a difference at that point). Other than that, there are plenty such, just not as plenty plenty plenty as there are that are as your picture.

Comment: Well thanks, I will try the upside down package then :)

Comment: Sure this is not a [a shopping or buying recommendation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help)?

Comment: Yes, any transistor would have been good. I just needed the solution to the reversed pins problem, hence I accepted the answer below even though that transistor isn't at any close-by supplier. Also I won't even use a reversed package since I can't find one, I'll just try and solder the transistor on its back and hope it looks good enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the order code typically has a suffix R for Reverse

bc847  and bc847R  emitter base swapped.